# Elasticsearch 6.2 search by array each item

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have array set like this,

```
"title": "Living furniture exhibitions!"
"include_products": ["ikea chair", "marketO desk"]
```

And I try to search like this.

```
{
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "ikea desk",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
}
```

I do not want any search result. But, It searched by ["**ikea** chair", "marketO **desk**"].

How can I search each item in include_products array?

Also, my mapping setting like this,

```
"mappings": {
    "information" : {
      "properties" : {
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "include_products": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
{
      "query":{
          "bool":{
              "must":[
                  {
                      "match_phrase":{
                          "include_products":"ikea desk"
                      }
                  }    
              ]
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's Cool... You save my time... And, I have one more question. Can I search all fields using "match_phrase" ?

Comment: Thank you, sir! I also combine phrase and multi_match!